# Test lastIndex of two string

Tags: javascript, string

Assume this function:

```
function renameDoc() {
    var newFilename = prompt("Name this document:", filename);
    if (newFilename !== null) {
      if (newFilename === "") {
        changeFilename(); // "untitled.txt"
      } else {
        changeFilename(newFilename.lastIndexOf(".txt") == -1 ?
          newFilename + ".txt" : newFilename);
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

This function tests if `newFilename` has `.txt` at the last. and this works perfectly.

But want to check if `newFilename` has `.txt.` or `.md`

I'm trying this

```
function renameDoc() {
    var newFilename = prompt("Name this document:", filename);
    if (newFilename !== null) {
      if (newFilename === "") {
        changeFilename(); // "untitled.txt"
      } else {
        changeFilename((newFilename.lastIndexOf(".txt") && newFilename.lastIndexOf(".md")) == -1 ?
          newFilename + ".txt" : newFilename);
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

It seems to be not working perfectly.

Can you help me on this.

Comment: you can use `||` condition instead.

Comment: AND not OR.  If last index is -1, that means the string isn't in the text.  Checking that both are equal to -1 means the file doesn't end with .txt or with .md so it's appropriate to append .txt to those files.  Using the OR condition doesn't yield useful information, because it returns FALSE only when the file ends with both .txt and .md which is not possible.

Comment: @La-comadreja you're right. i missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this:

```
/\.(md|txt)$/.test(newFilename)
```

to test if a file name ends with either ".md" or ".txt"

In your function, you may do this:

```
changeFilename(
    /\.(md|txt)$/.test(newFilename)
        ? newFilename
        : newFilename + ".txt"
);
```

Comment: Mine is closer to what was originally implemented and simpler in syntax.

Comment: @user3317779 if you want better in performance then go with La-comadreja's solution and if you want small code then go with this code.

Comment: @La-comadreja yea you used `lastIndexOf` but now I'm thinking which one should I use.

Comment: If you have a lot of file names, then it is easy to add them to my solution by separating them with `|` symbols. For two file names there is no difference between our solutions. Also, you can do a case-insensitive test by changing my solution to say `...)$/i.test(...`. Adding the `i` flag will match and accept either .TXT or .txt just the same.

Comment: As versatile as Regexes are, they do tend to make the code harder to read.  This looks reasonable and concise though.

Answer (score 2):

```
(newFilename.lastIndexOf(".txt") === -1 && newFilename.lastIndexOf(".md") === -1)
```

the statement is checking that it DOESN'T have .txt and DOESN'T have .md. For example, it returns true if it ends in .jpeg

Comment: This seem to be long...
Any simpler/small solution?

Comment: If you're testing 2 variables for equality to a certain integer, you need to perform the "equals" comparison on both variables.  Can't be shortened because it's a binary operator.